# Android: Trying to convert an app into a home screen widget

Tags: android, asynchronous, service, widget

I currently have a tiny app that looks up live sports scores and displays the same.
The main class calls an async task. The async task calls 2 procedures. The first one to parse an XML file and get an html link. The second one to read through that html file.

Now I want to convert this app into a home screen widget. How do I go about doing this?
Should I have a service or an async task or both? I'm really confused.

What would be the basic framework on which I need to plugin my existing code?
Please help?

Regards,
Sam

Answer (score 1):

this is a good tutorial http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

also there are some examples in the sdk